# No keyboard during Fedora 13 firstboot setup

Tags: linux, fedora-13

Good evening,

I have a Dell XPS M2010.  It came from the factory with Vista and was converted to Fedora 6 within a day of receiving it.  With the release of Fedora 8 it was upgraded.  With the release of Fedora 10, it was reinstalled from scratch.  Now I am trying to reinstall from scratch again while moving to Fedora 13.

The install itself goes smoothly enough (personal problems with trying to hunt down a blank DVD or large enough USB stick aside).  After the initial setup and copying the files to the HDD, the machine reboots and the DVD ejects as expected.  After the reboot, the firstboot procedure picks up and installation continues.  The third screen of firstboot is Create User.  The problem is, I can't create a user.  The keyboard does absolutely nothing, so I can't type my name.  Since creating a user is required, I can't bypass this screen.

During the DVD-based portion of installation, the keyboard worked just fine (root password and hostname were typed with no problem).  The mouse works just fine throughout the entire process.  Editing the GRUB prompt to start at Runlevel 3 brings me to text-based setup.  Like the GUI setup, I have no keyboard.  I can't use the arrow keys to move to the Keyboard configuration menu item.  None of the previous Fedora installs had this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm limited to an eeePC and cellphone while my big machine sits there doing nothing useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=538911) is for Fedora 12, but maybe it works with Fedora 13, too? Basically just in GRUB pass the amount of memory as a kernel parameter (`mem=xxxxxxxxxx`), where xxxxxxxx is the amount of RAM in kilobytes. For example, if your computer has 2 GB of RAM, then the value would be 2147483648 (2*1024*1024*1024).

Bugzilla claims that this workaround is needed only during the installation. I hope this bizarre tip helps you.

Comment: Except that it's already installed. This is on first boot.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but, as Mr. Vazquez-Abrams stated, this is after the bulk of the install, during first-boot (is this still considered part of Anaconda?).  The system is not hung, it simply will not accept (or does not interpret, or something) input from the keyboard.  The mouse continues to work, but there is nothing useful to click on.

As it is, the machine has been sitting idle for a week now as I can't bring myself to download an alternate distro.  I should get it back up and running as I've been using my eeePC and a machine with a CPU and motherboard that I bought in 2003.